# How to add feature column names to Keras Estimator

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to add feature column names to the inputs of a Keras model that I have converted to an Estimator. This will allow me to send a JSON message to a serving model where I can specify the feature names. My model is as follows, which has 3 input nodes:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(300, input_dim=3))
model.add(keras.layers.PReLU())
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I then create an estimator:

```
estimator_model = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model)
```

My custom input function is:

```
# Define input fn
def input_function(features, labels=None, shuffle=False):
  input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"dept_tenure": dept_tenure,
       "prior_tenure": prior_tenure,
       "employ_tenure": employ_tenure},
    y=labels,
    shuffle=shuffle
  )
  return input_fn
```

However, when I try to evaluate the model, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot find input with name "employ_tenure" in Keras Model. It needs to match one of the following: dense_4_input
```

`model.input_n` returns `[dense_4_input]`, where `dense_4` is the name of the first layer.

So how do I configure my model such that the feature names in my input function will match the input names of my model?

I've looked at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/programmers_guide/estimators#creating_estimators_from_keras_models), but its no help.

Comment: Have you tried to give your layers names as specified here?
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/new-in-tensorflow-14-converting-a-keras-model-to-a-tensorflow-estimator

Comment: Did you figure out the answer?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: @neurix I think the OP wants a vector of names for the features of that first, input layer, rather than a single name for the whole layer. Am I right OP?